# MiniTest testing wrong class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, shoulda

I am new to minitest, I have always used RSpec in the past. I have an issue where I put move an object into another table after its been deleted. So I have 2 classes named similar one that is namespace and the other is not. See below for a description in code. Some of the other gems I am using with minitest is minitest-spec-rails and shoulda. Any help is appreciated.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'users'
end
```

cache/user.rb

```
module Cache
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'cache_users'
  end
end
```

test/models/cache/user_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

module Cache
  class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    #this tests User not Cache::User
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried class Cache::UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

Comment: Yes, I am getting the same result.

Comment: You say "this tests User not Cache::User", but don't show how. Why do you think this?

Comment: This needs to Test Cache::User, but is testing the User, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this.

```
class Cache::UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  @model = Cache::User #this tell what we're testing
end
```